# Watson Bucket P1

Tags: .net, exception, clr

everyone!

I have a watson bucket with the information below:

```
EventType clr20r3

P1 4h5ws4fg4i3sv14bgrioya42410akt5e 
P2 1.0.0.0
P3 54907f70
P4 system.data
P5 2.0.0.0
P6 4889deaf
P7 28dc
P8 0
P9 system.nullreferenceexception
P10 NIL
```

But I don't understand why the P1 (EXE Name) is that way, maybe it is encrypted? Maybe a GUID from Assembly Information?

Can you help me understand that information? What is it?

I am asking that because I have a large list of assemblies to search for the unhandled exception and understanding how to correctly read the watson bucket would help a lot.

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is basically taking the Base32 encoding of a (SHA1?) hash of the executable. The P1 field has a 32 character limit, and if it can't make the executable name fit (e.g. by chopping off the .exe), then it does this instead.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2012/06/08/net-framework-error-message-in-the-event-log-ambiguity.aspx for details.